# select element previous to another, using only CSS

Tags: css

I want to put a green color to the element i that has the "valid" class next to it, using only css.

```
<i>Hello</i>
<input type="text" class="valid">

.valid ~ i
{
 color: #00c851 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4tubpkv/

Comment: That may be what you want, but if the elements are placed in that order in the DOM then, to quote Mick Jagger: "*you can't always get what you want.*" There is, in CSS, no previous-sibling selector, you can, however, reorder the elements and place them - visually - in that order using CSS Grid or Flexbox.

Comment: @DavidThomas I did not know who he was, but I realize then that it is impossible?

Comment: Basically, you can change the order in the DOM but "play" with css to present it in reverse. (Using `float` or with `flexbox`)

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that by CSS. There is no `"previous sibling"` selector.